# Does the Open Mapping Theorem generalise to arbitrary Riemann surfaces?

Tags: complex-analysis

If M and N are arbitrary, not necessarily connected Riemann surfaces, then is a non-constant holomorphic map between them necessarily an open map?

Comment: $f : \Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ given by $z\mapsto 0$ is not open.

Comment: My apologies. I meant non-constant holomorphic map.

Comment: Choose an atlas for $M$, so you work on connected open sets $U_\alpha\subseteq M$ which are isomorphic to connected opens $V_\alpha\subseteq\Bbb C^n$. The continuous image of a connected space is connected, so you get the result for the chart $U_\alpha$, provided $f$ is not constant on any connected component of $M$. Then since the $U_\alpha$ cover $M$ and $\left.f\right|_{U_\alpha}$ is open for all $\alpha$, $f$ is open.

Comment: @Stahl Why are you concerned about connectedness? Also, you should put this as an answer. EDIT: Oh, I see the OP mentioned this expicitly. Yeah, the proof has nothing to do with connectedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : M\to N$ be a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces which is not constant on any connected component $M_\alpha$ of $M$. Working on a sufficiently fine chart $\Bbb C\supseteq V_\beta\cong U_{\alpha,\beta}\subseteq M_\alpha$ for $M_\alpha$, you can see that the open mapping theorem applies to $\left. f\right|_{M_\alpha}$ (if you're worried about $N$ not being connected, you can see that it doesn't matter because $\left. f\right|_{M_\alpha}(M_\alpha) = f(M_\alpha)\subseteq N$ is connected), so $\left. f\right|_{M_\alpha}$ is open for all $\alpha$. Then since $\bigcup_\alpha M_\alpha = M$ and each $\left. f\right|_{M_\alpha}$ is open, $f$ itself is open. Note that it is not enough that $f$ is nonconstant, you must require that it is nonconstant on each connected component.

Comment: J-money -- $n=1$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis o yeah u right it's a surface